# slub_min_objects : How comes 0 can stand as a valid / default value / rationale?

Tags: linux, virtual-memory, kernel-parameters, high-performance

In the comments of the source code (`mm/slub.c`) of my linux_5.4 kernel, I can read :

```
In order to reach satisfactory performance we must ensure that a minimum
number of objects is in one slab. Otherwise we may generate too much
activity on the partial lists which requires taking the list_lock. This is
less a concern for large slabs though which are rarely used.
```

My understanding of *"a minimum number of objects"* is whatever **> 0**

From some benchmarks achieved under some linux-4, I had even understood that the optimal value had been found to be 2 * Number of CPUs.

In the documentation (Documentation/vm/slub.rst) I can read :

> .. slub_min_objects=x     (default 4)

Having 2 cores I feel happy with that default value. However, my bootlog tells :

```
SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=2, Nodes=1
```

Of course I can set `slub_min_objects=4` as part of my boot command line and successfully get MinObjects=4. However, I would like to understand how comes the default value went down to 0 ?

Have things changed elsewhere in linux kernel justifying that 0 is actually the best possible value ? or that we should in fact no longer care about this as a condition for better performance ?

---

**UPDATE 1** : Following first comment from @Paul_Pedant

The trace in the bootlog appears to be the result of the following instruction :

`pr_info("SLUB: HWalign=%d, Order=%u-%u, MinObjects=%u, CPUs=%u, Nodes=%u\n",cache_line_size(),slub_min_order, slub_max_order, slub_min_objects,nr_cpu_ids, nr_node_ids);`

slub_min_order being set following :

```
get_option(&str, (int *)&slub_min_objects);
```

This obviously confirms Paul_Pedant's guess : ***"the bootlog is reporting the user-supplied value"***

The following code might give light to the value that will actually be used representing the minimum number of objects :

```
min_objects = slub_min_objects;
if (!min_objects)
    min_objects = 4 * (fls(nr_cpu_ids) + 1);
```

That is to say either the boot command line parameter or a default value based on the number of cpus. Which, in my case (2 cpus, position of the most significant set bit = 2) :

min_objects=4*(2+1)= **12**

Default for 4 <= CPUs < 8 would be 16,
Default for 8 <= CPUs < 16 would be 20

And BTW, the documented default value of 4 possibly dating from single processor systems.

This question could be said closed if I could find somewhere some rationale behind the scaling.